# Copiar select e manter selectedIndex

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou mexendo com um Select, onde seto sua index. O problema que após setar a index tenho que coloca-lo dentro de uma div.

Só que ele não recebe a index setada, ele vai com a default. Qual função do jquery, corta o select com o que foi atribuído a ele, para eu poder fazer a inserção do que desejo.

```
<select class="my">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select class="menor">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".my, .menor").prop('selectedIndex', -1);     
        $(".my").after("<div class='maior'></div>").prependTo(".maior");
});
```

Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/6wxfaLwp/

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar assim para copiar o index de um select para outro:

```
var index = $(this).prop('selectedIndex'); // $(this) ou um seletor que dê o select original
$(".menor").prop('selectedIndex', index);  // $(".menor") ou um selector que dê o select de destino
```

Um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/qy73oc6r/

Para inserir o `.menor` dentro de uma div nova podes usar o [`.wrap()` do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) com

```
$(".my").wrap("<div class='maior'></div>");
```

Um exemplo dos dois a funcionar juntos: https://jsfiddle.net/7w6zqrbL/

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar. Deu para entender o que você quiz dizer, mas na minha situação, é quando carrega ready() a página. Pois eu tenho que setar para depois copiar para dentro. Tentei -1 e sem sucesso: https://jsfiddle.net/7w6zqrbL/4/

Comment: @abcd então queres que fique sem nenhuma opção setada? assim? -> https://jsfiddle.net/7w6zqrbL/5/

Comment: É um plugin, daí quando a pessoa carrega, ela pode setar como -1, ou qualquer outro valor, caso ela sete um número muito alto do que os options existentes ele retorna -1.  Então eu crio abaixo do select umas divs (simulando um select), depois jogo o select dentro da div pai. Após jogar tento pegar as opções. Consegui realizar o que desejava, clonando e depois pegando a index da principal e jogando para a clonada. ATT

Comment: @abcd desculpa, mas não entendo ainda o que queres fazer. Acho que tens a ideia bem clara mas ainda não colocaste aqui informacão sufeciente para quem não conhece a tua app perceber o que queres. Eu gostava de melhorar a minha resposta, mas preciso de perceber melhor. Senão a pergunta e resposta não são uteis para mais ninguém :P

Comment: eu adicionei a resposta ao tópico, da maneira que consegui resolver. Como eu disse, eu clonei o select principal e coloquei dentro da DIV que criei, daí pego a index selecionada do select principal e passo para o select  clonado e depois removo o select principal. Eu peguei a sua ideia de passar de um select para o outro o item selecionado (selected) ... ATT

Comment: @abcd porque tens 2 selects no HTML? é só para o exemplo ou é assim na tua app? qual deles é o principal?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer da seguinte maneira:

Ao invés de usar apenas prependTo, eu clonei:

```
clone().prependTo()...

$(html).find("select").prop('selectedIndex', $(this).find(":selected").index());
$(this).remove();
```